Would I regret removing ragged fiberglass batting from ceiling of old house basement?
We live in 130-yr-old house in MA. Some previous owner installed fiberglass insulation between the joists over the basement. The basement's walls are uninsulated stone and the floor is a mix of badly poured cement (2/3) and stone placed over plastic sheets (1/3). The house is heated by steam and the boiler in the basement keeps it fairly warm down there all winter. There is some moisture on the walls and floor in the summer (especiallyl after heavy rains) but no water. I run a dehumidifier in the summer to keep it drier. The existing insulation in the ceiling is filthy and hanging in shreds in places. Would I be giving up anything of value by removing it to clean the place up a bit? I'd love to remove mouse habitat and there is no concern about noise abatement. Advice?

we do not know what your regrets are, and how susceptible you are to having regrets ... please ask about the problem,  not about your future feelings

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

For anyone who wants to know:  Climate in MA.

In our (MA) climate, insulating the basement ceiling is mostly a matter of keeping the floor above it from chilling your feet in winter. If you wear slippers or have rugs, that's less of an issue. It barely affects energy use.
If the basement itself is insulated and/or heated, this is even less needed.
It may help very slightly, so if you don't have a reason to remove it you can certainly leave it. But removing it is almost certainly defensible.
I currently have rock wool batting there, put in at almost no cost under the utilitys' energy efficiency program. But even the folks who installed it told me that the greatest benefit was going to come from air sealing and from improving the attic insulation. And now my basement is better heated and better insulated, so heat loss downward will be even lower.

If it barely affects energy use it barely affects the temperature of the floor. You're contradicting yourself. I agree that air sealing is more important.

@isherwoid: No. Cold floor does not affect heating cost much;  amount of heat lost depends on the amount of temperature difference, so loss to a 50 degree basement through a 60 degree floor is a lot less than to a 30 degree winter. This is part if why the single biggest bang for the buck, after air sealing, is insulating the attic (the warmest layer indoors); walls are a moderately distant second and floors more distant. Also, air temperature tends to stratify, so the difference is less at floor than higher. I don't know enough thermodemonics to give you a mathematical model.

Obviously it was installed for a reason. You say that the basement is "fairly warm", but not what that means in Fahrenhoozles. The bottom line is that heat transfer occurs in proportion to temperature differential. What does that mean? The greater the temperature difference between your living space and your basement, the less efficient your home is from an energy perspective. It'll also feel less warm, since the floor and the air near it will now be cooler.
To really know the effects you'd have also had to tell us something about your climate. If a "cold" day is 45 degrees for a few hours, it's all negligible. If it's minus 45, like we might see in northern Minnesota on occasion, that's a different kettle of worms.

Unfortunately, sometimes the reason is additional vendor profit, which was a large part of the reason in my case. Or it may be a comfort matter, but a minor one.

You might also consider the effect during summer.  If the basement is warmer than you want the upstairs to be, the heat will rise and warm the upstairs.
That said, if the insulation is dirty, it wouldn't hurt to remove it and replace it (possibly with something less vulnerable to mice).  And if you're doing that, you could remove it immediately and worry about replacing it later.  If you find that it causes problems, you can always replace it sooner.  If you don't, you can delay replacing it until never.

Heat doesn't rise. Warm air rises within its surrounding air. While that can happen in the basement, the only way heat transfers to the upper leven is through conduction. That's what the insulation slows.

Heat transfers to the upper level via convection.  That's why people airseal -- there are holes in the ceiling/floor that allow air flow.  Yes, some heat will transfer via conduction and radiation, but convection is more efficient.  Particularly since the heat that matters is in the air.  If you want to learn more about this, I suggest that you ask in Physics.SE.
